Teradata SQL to see if customer has unique National Insurance Number
I have a list of customers and each customer should have a distinct national insurance number assigned. Some customers will have the same NIN. How do I write the query to check whether each customer has a unique NIN?
This is what I've tried, later in the script I aggregate the total of those that are unique.
SUM(CASE WHEN Natinsnbr is not null and natinsnbr <> '' THEN 1 END)
OVER (PARTITION BY NINNBR ORDER BY UPDATEDTTM DESC) 
AS UNI_NINNBR

Sample Data:



customer number
ninnbr




123
AA111111AA


456
AA111111AA


678
AA111111AA


910
AB123456AB


109
AC123456AB


549
AD123456AD


295
AD123456AD


743
AE123456AE


443
AF123456AF


903
AG123456AG



Output would then hopefully look like:



customer number
ninnbr
Unique




123
AA111111AA
3


456
AA111111AA
3


678
AA111111AA
3


910
AB123456AB
1


109
AC123456AB
1


549
AD123456AD
2


295
AD123456AD
2


743
AE123456AE
1


443
AF123456AF
1


903
AG123456AG
1



Later in the script I'll aggregate based on unique = 1

could you please show some sample data and desired output?

Is the concern one "customer" having multiple (nonblank) NIN or multiple customers being associated with the same NIN? (Or both)

@Fred both, customers can free-hand their entry, some customers won't have one at all

I would think that removing ORDER BY UPDATEDTTM DESC would do the trick.

I have tried in mysql based on sample data and expected output, syntax should be very similar to Terradata.
Fiddle
SELECT 
    c.customer_number,
    c.ninnbr,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ninnbr) AS unique_count
FROM 
    customers c
ORDER BY 
    c.ninnbr, c.customer_number;

Output

